# Python - Nested lists - Call nested indexes of sublist

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a list with nested sublists like this:

```
my_list = {'active': {'type': 'boolean', 'string': 'Active'}, 'name': {'type': 'char', 'string': 'Title'}, 'description': {'type': 'html', 'string': 'Description'}, 'priority': {'type': 'selection', 'string': 'Priority'}, 'product': {'type': 'char', 'help': 'Selected product by user', 'string': 'Product'}}
```

You can notice that sublists doesn't have always the same content: `'type'`, `'string'` and sometimes `'help'`.

I can run a basic `for` loop to display elements of the list:

```
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

Which returns to me:

```
active
name
description
priority
product
```

But how can I loop through items of the sublists? I think I need to nest an other `for` loop.

I want to display specifics information like:

```
- Active: active, boolean
- Title: name, char
- Description: description, html
- Priority: priority, selection
- Product: product, char, Selected product by user
```

Comment: Those are dictionaries, not lists. Use `.items()` to iterate over key-value pairs in a dict

Comment: Your desired output does not match the input? Please add more details about what you want to show

Comment: `for j in my_list[i]:`  will iterate the internal dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first thing first. This is not a list. This is a nested dictionary or `dict` in Python. Here is a link that shows you the differences: [Difference between List and Dictionary in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-list-and-dictionary-in-python/)

You can refer to a dict element via it's key name. for example:

```
my_list['active'] # {'type': 'boolean', 'string': 'Active'}
```

or when you don't sure that the specific key exists use the `get()` method. It will return `None` if there is no key with the specified name. To get the output you want, here's a quick solution:

```py
for elem in my_list:
    output = f'{my_list[elem]["string"]}: {elem}, {my_list[elem]["type"]}'
    is_help = my_list[elem].get("help")
    if is_help:
        output = f'{output}, {is_help}'
    print(output)
```

this will be printed:

```
Active: active, boolean
Title: name, char
Description: description, html
Priority: priority, selection
Product: product, char, Selected product by user
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion between list and dictionary. `get()` method is the way, thanks.